# Redirect shell script stderr to syslog

Tags: linux, shell, stderr, io-redirection, syslog

I often see that both stdout and stderr are piped to the syslog. However, it is then no longer possible to distinguish in syslog whether it was an error or not. Message severity is always info (or what I set with -p option of the one single logger command). How to solve this problem? In concrete terms it is about my backup script sends an error with `echo "Error occurred...!" >&2`

The script runs as a cron job by the following statement:

```
/root/bin/backup 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -t backup -i
```

Comment: You can log your stderr and stdout to different locations if that's what you want. It's not entirely clear what your exact problem is.

Comment: No, same location (system log), but different severity to enable filtering and monitoring (see https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/properties.html#message-properties)

Comment: I'm not aware about rsyslog but I understand that you want to preprocess the messages in your stderr before writing them to the same file, is that correct?

Comment: @Amit Singh Each log entry has a severity. Normally it is "info" (code 6). And per default the severity is not shown in /var/log/syslog. But using a monitoring tool like Lggr, one can filter by severity and do some further actions like alerts on critical messages.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily pipe the stdout and stderr separately to different commands:

```
{ some_command 2>&3 | logger -t OUTPUT -i; } 3>&1 | logger -t ERROR -i
```

Options:

> - `-i`
>
>   Log the PID of the **logger** process with each line. [ref](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/bsdutils/logger.1.en.html)

> - `-p`, `--priority` *priority*
>
>   Enter the message into the log with the specified *priority*. The priority may be specified numerically or as a facility.level pair. For example, `-p` **`local3.info`** logs the message as informational in the **local3** facility. The default is **user.notice.** [ref](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/bsdutils/logger.1.en.html)

> (*tim* uses the example of `-p user.error` in a comment below) [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090057/redirect-shell-script-stderr-to-syslog#comment113364505_64090813)

> - `-t`, `--tag` *tag*
>
>   Mark every line to be logged with the specified tag. The default tag is the name of the user logged in on the terminal (or a user name based on effective user ID). [ref](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/bsdutils/logger.1.en.html)

> (The TAG is a string of ABNF alphanumeric characters that MUST NOT exceed 32 characters.) [ref](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3164#section-4.1.3)

Examples:

```
# { ls -d /etc /etx 2>&3 | logger -t OUTPUT -i; } 3>&1 | logger -t ERROR -i
# tail -n2 /var/log/messages
Sep 27 16:30:12 xxxx ERROR[4138]: ls: cannot access '/etx': No such file or directory
Sep 27 16:30:12 xxxx OUTPUT[4140]: /etc
```

```
( some_command 2>&3 | logger -t SOMECOMMAND -i; ) 3>&1 | logger -t SOMECOMMAND -i -p user.error
```

Comment: After adding the option -p user.error the error message also gets the desired message severity: 3,1,Sep 28 20:33:58,v2201911106801100891,ERROR[25406]:, ls: cannot access '/etx': No such file or directory